# Automatically detect and drop unwanted features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning

I am new to Data Analysis in Pandas. Is there any possibility to **automatically detect all the unwanted features** like ID, Name, Address (assume its not required), DateTime (assume its not required) in Pandas ?

- Input is any dataframe with both useful and useless features.
- Output
  should be a new dataframe without the unwanted features.

Here **I am trying to do classification, unsupervised learning (without target feature)** but I dont need ID, Name, Address etc.

*I used df.info() and removing all the features that has dtype of 'object' but I am missing some other important categorical features too.*

If there is a possibility, could anyone help me with explanation ?

Comment: Hi, That's not how you remove features. Try this link... https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/dimensionality-reduction-techniques-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do that with python pandas. You can manually delete the unwanted columns with pandas' drop() function.

For example:

```
df.drop(['col1', 'col2'], axis=1)
```